# CodeBlocks Management Window Only Shows Resources

Tags: codeblocks

[This is what my CodeBlocks Management window looks like currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mife1.png)

[This is what I expect it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmA8D.png)

The only visible tab is "Resources", when I expect there to be "Projects", "Files", and "FSymbols" tabs.
Apologies if I'm missing any details I should've provided.

I've tried setting the perspective to Code::Blocks default, reopening the project, restarting CodeBlocks, messing around with the "View" toolbar, reinstalling CodeBlocks completely, and it still looks the same.

I'm not very experienced with this program, and I'm not sure what I should try next.